# How to match a button to an image?

Tags: actionscript-3, button, random, click, mouseevent

I'm creating a image matching program which randomly displays an image at the top.  The user needs to choose a matching image from a list of choices, and upon a good match it displays a message, and on a bad match it ends the game.

How can I determine if `Elegir1` button is a match to the `persoanje 1`?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Card Game]

**Code:**

```
DiabloB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Elegir1)
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Caida)

function Caida(e: Event) {
    T++
    if (T == 10) {
        T = (Math.random() * 4 + 1)

        //this is the random IMG "Personaje 1, Personaje 2 , Personaje 3 , Personaje 4"
        refClass = getDefinitionByName("Personaje " + T) as Class;
        ref = new refClass()
        ref.y = -250
        addChild(ref)
        T = -500
        enemigos.push(ref)
        trace(enemigos.length)
        setTimeout(function () {
            removeChild(ref);
        }, 20500);
    }
}

// this is the button 
function Elegir1(e: MouseEvent) {

}
```

Comment: English does not appear to be the author's native language.  Cleaned up formatting of code, embedded the image shared, and added descriptive language to the question (removing it from the title).  Also added a more succinct title.

Answer (score 0):

The [MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) gives you access to the [currentTarget](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget). The target is a [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) with a [name](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name). Create a conditional on click where you compare the two. Then, run your respective functions for each result.